# As far as I know, const variables are immutable. How come this is possible?

Tags: javascript, constants, immutability

And I would be also interested, what "this" keyword is referring to? I do not understand what is going on in this code snippet, never seen such behavior before.

```
const var_name = 'abcd';
const n = 120;
this[var_name] = n;
console.log(this[var_name]) //120
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly is troubling you. in your case `this` refers to some object that wraps execution context of this snippet (that might be `window` or any arbitrary object just alike). What your code does - it declares and initializes two variables then it assigns the value of `n` to the property, named `'abcd'` (which is the value of `var_name`). After that you log the value of that property to the console, which is equal to `n` (as one might expect).

Comment: And the statement *'...const variables are immutable'* is not exactly correct, since you may do `const foo = {bar: 'baz'}`, while still be allowed to do `foo.baz = 'qux'` or, even, `foo.bar = 'qux'`.

Comment: What puzzles me is that the variable  "var_name" (declared with "const") got mutated by the value of "n", (120). I was taught this is not allowed.

Comment: You seem to be completely unaware of what exactly above code lines do. Aren't you? If you append `console.log(var_name)` to above lines, you can make sure that `var_name` variable ***DID NOT*** mutate and it is still equal to `'abcd'`.

Comment: You are correct - that is why I asked the question here. Like I said before, I have no idea what is going on. To be more precise, I do not know what this line of code means: "this[var_name] = n;" I know that this points to some object in the execution context, but I have no clue why it is in front of the var_name and why var_name is in parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also a beginner here, but from what I've understood from the snippet is:

```
'this[var_name] = n;'
```

"this" is an object and you've created a property called "var_name" for the object "this" and assigning a value of the const 'N".

to sum it all up,

`const var_name = 'abcd';` and `this[var_name] = n;`
are totally different because it's comparing a variable to an object.
hope this helps :D

Comment: Thanks, this really helped!!! Now I understand it!! I thought that var_name and this[var_name] were the same variable!